# Keyboard layout in Ubuntu 13.10 changes after restart

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

I've set my keyboard layout to be Irish but every time I restart the machine it reverts to some other layout (although it still says Irish in the settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the left of my cloud icon in the top right of my desktop there are two windows. It seems there is a value in this that was set to Macintosh (En) even though the language to the right was set to Irish. Fixed now